# kafka consumer AbstractCoordinator: Discovered coordinator Java client

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have 3 brokers running with broker id s 0 1 and 2. The Consumer (Java Client) picks up broker 0 as group coordinator and starts to consume messages correctly. But when the broker 0 which is the group coordinator is down, the consumer does not do anything and stalls on the poll() method. The process resumes only when that broker 0 is up and running.

How to handle this scenario of group co-ordinator change in the Java client?

I get this error when group coordinator dies:

```
16/09/22 17:42:45 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: Discovered coordinator datascience1.sv2.trulia.com:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) for group group2.
16/09/22 17:42:45 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: (Re-)joining group group2
16/09/22 17:42:45 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: Marking the coordinator datascience1.sv2.trulia.com:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead for group group2
```

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue, the producer keeps posting, but the consumer is stalled until coordinator is back.

Comment: What kafka version are you using?
is the log cleaner enabled? consumer offset topic is a compacted log, if log cleaner is disabled, this could lead to coordinator issues.

Comment: Does your topic has replication factor 3? Were all replicas synced with the leader?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50954843/7321097
and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50595475/7321097

The isue is in the offsets.topic.replication.factor & replication.factor configs.